# Ruby Prime Class Issues

Tags: ruby, primes

So I am running Ruby 1.9.3 and I am trying to use the Prime class.
I have added `require mathn` at the top of my .rb file

Other than the method name, this code came from the documentation page:
http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/prime/rdoc/Prime.html

```
def prime_number(n)
  Prime.each(n) do |prime|
    p prime 
  end
end  

prime_number(100)
```

Any ideas why this doesn't work? The error I get says

> undefined method each for `Prime:Class`

Comment: Hmm. Works for me as long as I do the require.

Comment: It has to work. *Prime* probably messed up somewehere between require and your method. Tried in irb:    `require 'mathn'  # true`     `Prime.respond_to? :each  # true`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried it in Ruby 1.9.3 and it worked. Tried it again in Ruby 1.8.7 and got your error message. A newer version of Ruby will probably solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you did `require mathn` and you must have `require 'mathn'` at the top of your file.

Either that, or you have neglected the quotes when you described your code above.